# Angular parse uint8Array response to Object Array

Tags: angular

I am working on a project involving MQTT and one of the topics I subbed to returns a uint8array payload (I am using ngx-mqtt).

```
     this.mqttService.observe('object1/data/').subscribe((message: IMqttMessage) => {
      const plainMessage = message.payload.toString();
      let updates = JSON.parse(plainMessage);
      this.dataService.updateMeasurements(updates);
 });
```

The `dataService.updateMeasurements` expects an array of type `MeasurementUpdate` with an `any[]` it does not work. How can I cast this any array to my specific array?

Comment: Please show how `MeasurementUpdate` is defined, the exact signature of `updateMeasurements` (from the data service) and what `updates` looks like. Also what do you mean by "does not work"?

Answer (score -1):

For `uint8array` you have to convert string character by character and then parse to JSON

For example (assuming message.payload is the `uint8Array`) :

```
 var plainMessage = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < message.payload.length; i++) {
        plainMessage += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(message.payload[i]));
    }
let updates = JSON.parse(plainMessage)
```

I am, away form my computer right now, so please mind the formatting and syntax.